# loacalhost vs127.0.0.1 in .env file in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I am very new to Laravel. I am using Homestead. When I try to any migration using php artisan migrate command I have to use DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 in the .env file. If I use localhost  instead of 127.0.0.1 if get the following error:
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Whereas, when I am using eloquent functionality in models and trying to populate the database I have to change DB_HOST in .env file to localhost i.e.  DB_HOST=localhost, if not then I get the following error:
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I have no idea about this. I am all confused. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Are you running artisan from within Homestead or from the host system?

Comment: @Camilo I am running artisan from the host system?? Where should we usually run artisan commands? within Homestead or the host system??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave it as `localhost` and try running artisan from within the Homestead virtual machine.

You can access the virtual machine with `homestead ssh` or `vagrant ssh`. Then move to the document root and run artisan from there.